# python regex songs

Tags: python, regex

sorry, I need some help finding the right regular expression for this.
Basically I want to recognize via regex if the following format is in a string:

artist - title (something)

examples:

```
"ellie goulding - good gracious (the chainsmokers remix)"
"the xx - you got the love (florence and the machine cover)"
"neneh cherry - everything (loco dice remix)"
"my chemical romance - famous last words (video)"
```

I have been trying but haven't been able to find the right regular expression.

```
regex = "[A-Za-z0-9\s]+[\-]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\s]+[\(]{1}[\s]*[A-Za-z0-9\s]*[\)]{1}"
```

help please!

Comment: Shouldn't something such as `^.*?-.*?\(.*?\)$` be sufficient for you? [Example](http://regexr.com/3atf2).

Comment: yip. that does the trick. sorry and thanks a lot.

Comment: Why'd you use `.*?` as opposed to just `.*` . Didn't get that part. I tried the following to group the lines by song by artist, title and something.  `r = re.compile(r'(.*)-(.*).*\((.*)\)')` - That quickly seemed to work - did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> songstring = 'ellie goulding - good gracious (the chainsmokers remix)'
>>> re.match(r'(.*?) - (.*?) (\(.*?\))', songstring).groups()
('ellie goulding', 'good gracious', '(the chainsmokers remix)')
```

Comment: @JanneKarila Thank you for the comment, I've updated my answer with a regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
regex = r"^[^\-]*-[^\(]*\([^\)]*\)$"
```